# How to solve optimization problem with 'pairwise equality' constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Suppose we have an optimization problem $P$ :

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\min\limits_{\theta \in S}  \space  L(\theta)\\
\end{aligned}
$$
with
$S=\{\theta| \forall k_1,k_2 \in \{1,\ldots, K\}, s_{k_i}(\theta) = s_{k_j}(\theta)\}$ for an array of real-valued constraint functions $s_{1},...,s_{K}$.

S can be rewritten as

$$
\begin{aligned}
S = &\{\theta|\forall k \in \{1,\ldots,K-1\}, s_k(\theta)=s_{k+1}(\theta)\}\\
= &\{\theta|\exists c\in\mathbb{R}, \forall  k=\{1,\ldots,K\}, s_k(\theta) = c\}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Now I consider the consider for a fixed value $c\in\mathbb{R}$ the optimization problem $P_{c}$

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\min\limits_{\theta \in S_c}  \space  L(\theta)\\
\end{aligned}
$$
where $$S_c=\{\theta| \forall k \in \{1,\ldots, K\},  s_{k}(\theta) = c\}$$
If I'm correct,  we have that $\forall c, S_c\subset S$, and that $S=\cup_{c\in\mathbb{R}} S_c$.

What can be said about the relationship between the solutions of $P$ and the solutions of $P_c$, supposing that they exist?

Comment: By “solutions” do you mean feasible solutions or optimal solutions?

Comment: I mean optimal solutions